# Crystal Reports print rundll32 issue

Tags: printing, crystal-reports

So we have Crystal Reports running on a server in a multi user environment. Crystal is used to send documents directly to printers on the local network. Today we noticed the server running at full load and multiple instances of rundll32 hogging all the CPU cycles.

On further investigation it seems that the rundll32 instances are Crystal Print jobs which have hung or otherwise not finished.

I have not been able to reproduce the error yet but does anyone have any suggestions as to what could be causing the rundll32 process to hang like that, and how to avoid it?

Killing the processes manually is not ideal but it's the only way to get the users back going again.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a bug in the printer driver when the 'Printer Notifications' options was enabled. The printer was low on toner, and was issuing a message to the server, which was then using 100% of the cpu.

I disabled the option in the driver and haven't had that issue since.